# r cannot break the while loop, with use of trycatch

Tags: r

The `err_flag` value is `TRUE` but the process still looping and printing "error".

[image]

Full Code:

```
while(TRUE) {

     tryCatch({

           some_result = some_function(some_para) 

     }, warning = function(war) {
         print("warning")
         err_flag = TRUE

     }, error = function(err) {
         print("error")
         err_flag = TRUE

     } , finally = {

     })       

     if(err_flag) {
         break 
         # break the while loop
     } 
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand how `tryCatch` works. You pass a function to its `error` argument. This function doesn't have a return value (although it should have one) but also doesn't have the side effect of creating/modifying `err_flag` in the global environment. `tryCatch` is a function that returns the result of the expression *or*  the return values of the error, warning, ... handling function. It is not a control flow construct.

Comment: @Roland, could you please offer the code on how to arrange it? So that, when an error occurs at some_result = some_function(some_para) , err_flag can help escape the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tryCatch` is for functional programming. It is not really suited for breaking out of control flow structures. I suggest to use `try` instead.

```
set.seed(1) #for reproducibility

while (TRUE) {
  res <- try({
    x <- sample(1:5, 1)
    if (x == 5) stop("error")
    x
  }, silent = TRUE)
  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    message("breaking loop")
    break
  } else message(sprintf("The number is %d.", res))
}
#The number is 2.
#The number is 2.
#The number is 3.
#breaking loop
```